# Choice of tool / software to show workflows diagram?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentation

I want to give a workflow presentation, to my boss at my office, I don't wanna do old ppt style preso, I was thinking (since I'm out of making ppt) for a long time, are there any cloud services or web 2.0 technologies that I can use to put my idea across more effectively and **fast**.

Earlier I worked in visio, but the style is not dynamic and user responsive like with other forms of presentations, and website you see on internet. I want my workflow to have dynamic feel to it. What are my options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prezi](http://www.prezi.com) is surely a great tool, it's simple to use and it's on-line. There was a similar tool, [Ahead](http://www.ahead.com/), but now the site seems not responding.

If you prefer something to be used offline, there are `dynamic SVG generators` like [Sozi](http://sozi.baierouge.fr/) and [Dizzy](http://dizzy.metafnord.org), which generate SVG pages and manage events for moving through your contents. I use sometimes Sozi and now (after the first tests) I find it quite simple to use.

There are alternatives whose output are `html + javascript pages`, like [impress.js](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js) (interesting) and [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js) (not tried).

Answer (score 1):

prezi.com is a cloud based service for this type of thing.
Good luck.